# Hiding the previous subtable

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I have a table with some data and a show details button. After clicking show, a subtable with detailed data appears. Now what I mean is that if I select a different record and click on show details, the previous subtable should be hidden. But now this doesn't happen and I load data from the last record clicked into all subtables. Can you somehow help me solve my problem?

```
@inject IModalService model
@inject IDialogService DialogService
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager;
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar;
@inject KolejkowanieServices kolejkowanie_s;

@page "/KolejkowanieOkna"
<center>
    <h1>Kolejka Zleceń</h1>
</center>

<MudTabs Elevation="2" Rounded="true" ApplyEffectsToContainer="true" PanelClass="pa-6">
    <MudTabPanel Text="Kolejkowanie zleceń">
        <MudPaper Elevation="25">
            <MudToolBar>
                <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Refresh" @onclick='Refresh' />
            </MudToolBar>
        </MudPaper>
        <MudTable T="KZlecen" Items="@kolejka_z" FixedHeader="true" FixedFooter="false" Height="@(fixed_header || fixed_footer ?"600px":"")" CustomHeader="true" CustomFooter="true" Dense="true" Hover="true" Bordered="true" Striped="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" MultiSelection="false">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>L.p.</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Nr. opt</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Numer ZLC</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Data odbioru</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Status</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Podstatus</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Typ profila</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Kolory</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Jednostak okienna</MudTh>
               
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd Style="font-size: 10px" DataLabel="L.p.">@(kolejka_z.IndexOf(context) + 1)</MudTd>
            <MudTd Style="font-size: 10px"  DataLabel="Nr. opt">@context.kod_opt</MudTd>
            <MudTd Style="font-size: 10px" DataLabel="Numer ZLC">@context.zlecenie</MudTd>
            <MudTd Style="font-size: 10px" DataLabel="Data odbioru">@context.date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</MudTd>
            <MudTd Style="font-size: 10px" DataLabel="Status">@context.stan</MudTd>
            <MudTd Style="font-size: 10px" DataLabel="Podstatus">@context.podstatus</MudTd>
            <MudTd Style="font-size: 10px" DataLabel="Typ profila">@context.dtypy</MudTd>
            <MudTd Style="font-size: 10px" DataLabel="Kolor">@context.kolor</MudTd>
            <MudTd Style="font-size: 10px" DataLabel="Jednostka okienna">@context.jednostki</MudTd>
                    <MudTd><MudButton Variant="Variant.Outlined" Size="Size.Small" OnClick="@(() => ToggleValue(context.srcdoc))"> <span> @(context.ShowDetails ? "Ukryj" : "Pokaż") </span></MudButton></MudTd> 
           
    </RowTemplate>
            <ChildRowContent>
                @if (context.ShowDetails)
                {
                    <MudTr>
                        <td colspan="6">
                            <MudCard Elevation="0">
                                <MudCardHeader>
                                    <CardHeaderContent>
                                        <MudText Typo="Typo.body1"><strong>@stan_o</strong></MudText>
                                    </CardHeaderContent>
                                </MudCardHeader>
                                <MudCardContent Class="pa-0">
                                    <MudTable  Items="@proc" Context="procencik" FixedHeader="@fixed_header" FixedFooter="false" Dense="true" Height="190px">
                                        <HeaderContent>
                                           
                                            <MudTh>Srcdoc</MudTh>
                                        </HeaderContent>
                                        <RowTemplate>
                                            <MudTd DataLabel="Indeks">@procencik.srcdoc</MudTd>
                                            <MudTd DataLabel="Ilość pozycji">@suma</MudTd>
                                        </RowTemplate>
                                    </MudTable>
                                </MudCardContent>
                            </MudCard>
                        </td>
                    </MudTr>
                }

            </ChildRowContent>
    <PagerContent>
            <MudTablePager PageSizeOptions="new int[]{30,50, 100,200}"  RowsPerPageString="Ilość wierszy na stronie:" />
        </PagerContent>
        
</MudTable>
```

```
    async void ToggleValue(int srcdoc)
    {


        proc = new List<Procents>();
        KZlecen proctmp = new KZlecen();
        proctmp = kolejka_z.First(f => f.srcdoc == srcdoc);
        proctmp.ShowDetails = !proctmp.ShowDetails;
        proc = await Task.Run(() => kolejkowanie_s.pobierz_aktualnystan(Convert.ToInt32(srcdoc)));
        suma = proc.Count();
        StateHasChanged();
        proc.Clear();

    }
```

It doesn't have to be super efficient. The most important thing is that it works.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is iterate through each open item in `kolejka_z` and set the `ShowDetails` to false:

```
async void ToggleValue(int srcdoc)
{
    KZlecen proctmp = new KZlecen();
    proctmp = kolejka_z.First(f => f.srcdoc == srcdoc);
    bool showDetails = proctmp.ShowDetails;
    foreach(KZlecen kZlecen in kolejka_z.Where(k => k.ShowDetails))
    { 
        kZlecen.ShowDetails = false;
    }
    proctmp.ShowDetails = !showDetails;
}
```

Here's a working snippet: [Mudblazor Closing Details on details opening](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GYmHFOvUxvICImuh). Which is an extension to https://mudblazor.com/components/table#table-with-related-data.

Comment: I messed something up. To be able to toggle the current one, save its state in a new variable and use it later. See my edit